# How to get input values through target.querySelector in angular6

Tags: angular

I am trying to get username and password input field values using target.querySelector but i am getting exception value is not found can some one suggest me please

### .html

```
 <input type="text" id="userName"/><br>
  <input type="text" id="password"/><br>
  <button (click)="sendValues($event)">Send</button>
```

### .ts

```
 sendValues(event): void {
    event.preventDefaults();
    const target = event.target;
    const userName = target.querySelector('#userName').value;
    const password= target.querySelector('#password').value;
    alert(userName+" "+password);
  }
```

Comment: 1) why do you use that and not use ngmodel? 2)  you can use window.querySelector

Comment: <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="str" value="hello world"/><br>

Comment: how  can i get above input field value in .ts class

Comment: i am getting undefined

Comment: alert(this.str) getting undefined can you please clarrify me

Comment: Read this https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: cant we set input value in html ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngModel` directive to bind to a class property.

Otherwise you can use templateRef variables and send data through the event binding.

```
<input type="text" id="userName" #username /><br>
<input type="text" id="password" #password /><br>
<button (click)="sendValues(username, password)">Send</button>
```

And in the handler you can directly access `username.value` and `password.value`

Comment: cant we set input value in html ?

Comment: i mean <input type="text" id="userName" value="helloworld"/> not possible to bind?

Comment: @Krish Yes, that is the why we have `ngModel` and two way binding. ex `<input type="text" id="userName" [(ngModel)]="myVar"/>`. Declare `myVar` in .ts file and see the result.

Comment: `ngModel` does a 2-way-binding so yes, you can.

Comment: how can i binding default value using ngModel

Comment: with out declering myVar  in .ts file cant we set default value?

Comment: If you are not declaring, then you cannot access it. You have to use forms in that case. Or the template reference shown above in the answer and access dom elements using `@ViewChild`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sendValues(event): void {
    event.preventDefaults();
    let elem: HTMLInputElement;
    elem = document.querySelector('#userName');
    const userName = elem.value;
    elem= document.querySelector('#password');
    const password=elem.value;
    alert(userName+" "+password);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular 14

```
const nameInView = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector(".name")
console.log("name", nameInView.textContent);
```